# parsing an XMPP stream with libxml2

Tags: c++, xml, xmpp, xml-parsing, libxml2

I'm a beginner when it comes to libxml2, so here is my question:
I'm working at a small XMPP client. I have a stream that I receive from the network, the received buffer is fed into my Parser class, chunk by chunk, as the data is received. I may receive incomplete fragments of XML data:

`<stream><presence from='user1@dom`

and at the next read from socket I should get the rest:

`ain.com to='hatter@wonderland.lit/'/>`

The parser should report an error in this case.

I'm only interested in elements having depth 0 and depth 1, like stream and presence in my example above. I need to parse this kind of stream and for each of this elements, depth 0 or 1, create a  xmlNodePtr (I have classes representing stream, presence elements that take as input a xmlNodePtr). So this means I must be able to create an xmlNodePtr from only an start element like , because the associated end element( in this case) is received only when the communication is finished.

I would like to use a pull parser.

What are the best functions to use in this case ? xmlReaderForIO, XmlReaderForMemory etc ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want a push parser using [xmlCreatePushParserCtxt](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlCreatePushParserCtxt) and [xmlParseChunk](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlParseChunk).  Even better would be to choose one of the [existing open source C libraries for XMPP](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/).  For example, [here](https://github.com/metajack/libstrophe/blob/master/src/parser_libxml2.c) is the code from [libstrophe](https://github.com/metajack/libstrophe) that does what you want already.

Comment: If I use a push parser, how can I create xmlNodePtr objects ?

Comment: Check out that code from strophe.  It does exactly what you want.  You create callbacks for startElement, endElement, etc.